# Which K-factor (metal bending) is defined first, ANSI or DIN?

Tags: standards, metal-folding

## Description

We had been through several issues with K-factor handling of two teams due to the same name assigned by different standards.

ANSI and DIN has defined the same term for the same purpose. However they defined different reference points, so there is a serious ambiguation: [K-factor (ANSI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bending_(metalworking)#K-factor), [K-factor (DIN)](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biegeverk%C3%BCrzung)

Expected behavior from the latter institute would be it should have chosen some different name for the "their" K-factor; like L-factor or M-factor (who cares?).

## Question

I'm trying to find out the responsible institute that defined the same term without doing a research and caused the confusion. I couldn't get any helpful documents from the internet. Where can I find which K-factor is declared first?

Comment: Surely this is about the two parties not checking the detail properly, not which was defined first.

Comment: Considering you might not know what K-factor is, it's a unitless term so we had no possibility to determine who uses which standard. See the Wikipedia page, search the page for "ANSI" or "standard", you won't get any results. Giant internet points only a few results about this difference: [here is one](https://support.ptc.com/help/creo/ced_modeling/r20.2.0.0/en/index.html#page/ced_modeling%2FOSDM_Modules%2FSheetMetal_adm_allow.html%23wwID0EDVS3B)

Comment: If you use either standard ***correctly,*** you get the same result. If you just pick random numbers from the internet and stick them in random formulas, you get what you deserve - garbage.

Comment: You can't use either standard correctly without explicitly exchanging the standards institute name that the standard is defined by (ANSI or DIN in this case). See "Further explanation".

Comment: As for there being no errors when units are given, just see these : https://www.bbc.com/news/magazine-27509559